# Play 2 Multiple BodyParser

Tags: playframework-2.0

How to make a controller's action method containing two different bodyparser? For example,

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.FormUrlEncoded.class)
public static Result register() {

    RequestBody body = request().body();
    JsonNode node = body.asJson();
    Map<String, String[]> map = body.asFormUrlEncoded();

    if(node != null) {
        return ok("Got: " + node);
    } else if (map != null) {
        return ok("Got: " + map);
    } else {
        return badRequest("Expecting application/json request body");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it adheres to conventions to allow a single method to parse two different encodings. You basically want two controller functions in one. I think it's in best taste to have seperate methods handling the different encoding like so

```
private static void sharedApplicationLogic() { }

public static Result registerJSON() {
    JsonNode node = request().body().asJson();
    // Parse 
    sharedApplicationLogic();
}

public static Result registerFD() {
    Map<String,String[]> formdata = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded()
    // Parse
    sharedApplicationLogic();
}
```

You can then differentiate between these controller methods in your routes file

```
POST /register.json         controllers.Application.registerJSON()
POST /register.formdata     controllers.Application.registerFD()
```

(this isn't pretty RESTfulness, but you get the idea)

**Or** by determining this is in a controller function. I find this quite ugly but I guess it's the answer you're looking for. The trick is to omit the `@BodyParser` annotation:

```
public static Result register() {

    RequestBody body = request().body();
    JsonNode node = body.asJson();
    Map<String, String[]> map = body.asFormUrlEncoded();

    if(node != null) {
        return registerJSON(node);
    } else if (map != null) {
        return registerFD(map);
    } else {
        return badRequest("Expecting application/json request body");
    }
}
```

As far as I know, there's no prettier way to do this. There probably shouldn't be, because you want to map two different methods onto a single one.